Patch item to update description
I'm trying to use the PATCH endpoint from the APS Data Management API https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/items/:item_id
to update file descriptions in ACC. The request body is:
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "items",
    "id": "{Item_Id}",
    "attributes": {
      "extension": {
                     "data": {
                        "description": "new description"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But I keep getting an error:
"status": "400",
        "code": "BAD_INPUT",
        "title": "One or more input values in the request were bad",
        "detail": "Request input is invalid for this operation."

Do you know if the Data Management API supports this?

Autodesk Data Management PATCH  projects/:project_id/items/:item_id does not support updating displayName and description of the item. Currently, none of the APIs support this. It is, however, on the wishlist under ticket: 'FDM-3886 - Allow modification of [Description] field for Items' to be availed.

Adding a description is not supported at this stage.
